# Trying to insert a datagridview's values into a table iteratively using parameters

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, parameters

So I've been trying to use a datagridview to add new rows into my database. I would prefer not to load the entire database into the grid beforehand and refresh it. I just want to add the values from the datagrid into the table. I can't figure out a workaround. If I do it normally it will give me the error that all variables need to be unique. I have tried to add the sqlconnection.parameters.clear() function but then it seems that it makes all the values go empty and gives me an error that I am not supplying the neccessary information for the parameters.

```
string TicketTableInsertString = "INSERT INTO ticketTable (TicketID, num1, num2,num3,num4,num5) VALUES (@TicketID,@num1,@num2,@num3,@num4,@num5)";

        SqlConnection sqlConn;
        connString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-30191JE\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False";
        sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connString);

        try
        {
            sqlConn.Open();
            int ticketID=0;
            SqlCommand selectTicketIDCMD = new SqlCommand(selectTicketIDString, sqlConn);
            SqlCommand mainTableInsertCMD = new SqlCommand(MainTableInsertString, sqlConn);
            SqlCommand ticketTableInsertCMD = new SqlCommand(TicketTableInsertString, sqlConn);
            ticketID = (int)selectTicketIDCMD.ExecuteScalar()+1;
            sqlConn.Close();


            for (int i = 0; i < dgv_ticket.Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                ticketTableInsertCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TicketID", ticketID);             
                ticketTableInsertCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@num1", dgv_ticket.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
                ticketTableInsertCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@num2", dgv_ticket.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
                ticketTableInsertCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@num3", dgv_ticket.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
                ticketTableInsertCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@num4", dgv_ticket.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
                ticketTableInsertCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@num5", dgv_ticket.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
                sqlConn.Open();
                ticketTableInsertCMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
                sqlConn.Close();

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just clear sqlCommand parameters in start of for loop and set ticketID for each row:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgv_ticket.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            ticketID = (int)selectTicketIDCMD.ExecuteScalar()+1;
            ticketTableInsertCMD.Parameters.Clear();
            ticketTableInsertCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TicketID",  ...
```

Comment: mentioned that in my post I already attempted to. It instead gave a different error saying I was not supplying it with any values.

Comment: actually at this point I feel as though my IDE might be the one that got corrupted. It's started throwing error for nullreferences on random declaration statements.

Comment: define and instantiate ticketTableInsertCMD inside for loop, it would help.

Comment: also tried that, I cleared the parameters first and then had it reinstantiate directly after, didn't fix it =\

Comment: send me your source code: hamed_abutorabi@yahoo.com

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do it properly I added the parameters outside the loop and then just changed their values inside the loop.

```
                ticketTableInsertCMD.Parameters.Add("@TicketID", SqlDbType.Int);
                ticketTableInsertCMD.Parameters.Add("@num1", SqlDbType.Int);
                ticketTableInsertCMD.Parameters.Add("@num2", SqlDbType.Int);
                ticketTableInsertCMD.Parameters.Add("@num3", SqlDbType.Int);
                ticketTableInsertCMD.Parameters.Add("@num4", SqlDbType.Int);
                ticketTableInsertCMD.Parameters.Add("@num5", SqlDbType.Int);



            for (int i = 0; i < dgv_ticket.Rows.Count-1; i++)
            {
                ticketTableInsertCMD.Parameters["@TicketID"].Value = ticketID;
                ticketTableInsertCMD.Parameters["@num1"].Value = int.Parse(dgv_ticket.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                ticketTableInsertCMD.Parameters["@num2"].Value = int.Parse(dgv_ticket.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                ticketTableInsertCMD.Parameters["@num3"].Value = int.Parse(dgv_ticket.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
                ticketTableInsertCMD.Parameters["@num4"].Value = int.Parse(dgv_ticket.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString());
                ticketTableInsertCMD.Parameters["@num5"].Value = int.Parse(dgv_ticket.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString());
```